# ChartJs doesn't work on a local downloaded page of Circular Gauge chart example

Tags: javascript, ajax, graphics, chart.js

I've downloaded the following page:
http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Demos/VizGallery/#chart/circulargaugesbasicelementspaletteforranges

But when I open the local html shows a blank page. My idea was changing the example acording to my needs. Does anyone know how to make the local page works?

Answer (score 0):

That demo is accessible in ZIP packages which you can download from [ChartJS site](http://chartjs.devexpress.com)
You can open corresponding file

DevExpressChartJS-13.2.7.zip\Demos\VizGallery\demos\Circular Gauges\Basic Elements\Palette for Ranges.html

And modify it.

You also can mofify code directly on page which you linked using online code editor (but you won't be able to save results)

Comment: Hi, that URL is no longer available to download the demo, do you know where the ChartJS gauge example might found now?